# C Floating point exception: 8 - int and float

Tags: c, types, int

I came across something something new today as I was programming, and would love to know why that is. Basically, I set two variables a and b as an int. Here is the code below:

```
int main(){
int a = 1;
int b = 0;
if(a/b > 1 && b/a > 1){
    printf("True\n");
}
else{
    printf("False\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

When I set b equal to 0 it gives me the Floating point exception: 8 error, which is expected as I know it means I'm dividing something by 0. However, when I change a and b to float instead of int, like below:

```
int main(){
float a = 0;
float b = 1;
if(a/b > 0 && b/a > 0){
    printf("True\n");
}
else{
    printf("False\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The code runs smooth without any errors. Why is that possible, as I know I still end up dividing a number by 0?

Comment: Infinity has a floating point representation, but integer division by 0 causes a fault.

Comment: The `&&` operator short-circuits, so when `a / b > 0` evaluates to false, `b / a` is not computed.  Thus, in that case you *do not* end up dividing by zero.

Comment: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point numbers include +/- infinity

Comment: @JohnBollinger indeed the two code samples have more differences than just the variable type.